# Ruby version 1.9.3 vs 2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following Michael Hartl's Ruby tutorial book and the book says I should have Ruby 2.0.0 version. Since I have Ruby 1.9.3 version, I've tried various ways but it seems like I can't upgrade it to Ruby 2.0.0 version. Is it okay if I work code with Ruby 1.9.3 version and Rails 4.0.2?

Is it possible to have multiple Ruby or Rails versions within a computer? If so, how can that be achieved?

Thank you!

Comment: your friend - http://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/13.10

Comment: rvm or rbenv allow different Ruby versions, gemsets, etc.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I'm using mac OS X 10.8.5. I've installed rvm and tried to upgrade it to Ruby 2.0.0 using $rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p353.

Comment: And what does `which ruby` or `ruby --version` return? (And why did you ask if it's possible, then reply you already tried `rvm`?;)

Comment: Tell us what error you encounter when trying to install Ruby 2 with RVM. You may need just need to update RVM first (http://rvm.io/rvm/upgrading)

`rvm get head`
`rvm reload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Take a look at: https://rvm.io/ Thanks to this tool you have ability to awesome things with ruby versions. To have multiple versions of RoR you can use: http://rvm.io/gemsets
2. Sure, RoR 4.x is fully compatible with Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: It should be noted that Rails 4 prefers Ruby 2.0 but is compatible with 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use multiple versions of Ruby on one machine using RVM https://rvm.io/. (alternatively, try rbenv https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Perhaps you've installed 2.0.0 correctly with RVM, but you just aren't using the correct Ruby? Check RVM's setup with:

```
rvm current
```

That should output a string that begins with the version of Ruby that RVM is using. To change to using to 2.0.0 :

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```